# Are the row vectors in a row reduced echelon matrix always independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, independence

Are the row vectors in a row reduced echelon matrix always independent?

I'm thinking that since the first row is the only row with a non-zero coefficient, then it must be independent of all the others. Following that logic, the second row must be independent of the others as well; since we proved that it was independent of the first one and the 2nd row has a non-zero coefficient in the 2nd spot which all the later rows don't have... and so forth.

Is this correct?

Comment: The  *non-zero rows* are linearly independent.

Comment: The non-zero rows of a row reduced echelon matrix are always independent.

Comment: Is my reasoning for why the non-zero rows of a row reduced echelon matrix are independent correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deciding to answer my own question in case someone else on here is lost.

Independent vectors are vectors that cannot be written as a linear combination of each other. When we put a matrix into row reduced echelon form, we effectively see that if a row vector is not the zero vector, it can not be written in terms of the other vectors. As a result, row vectors in row reduced echelon form are independent of each other.